# Asp MVC Dropdown List Selected Value not selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following dropdown list but the selected value doesn't seem to working. It defaults to first item in list.

```
    private List<string> GetTransmissions()
    {
        List<string> Transmission = new List<string>();
        Transmission.Add("Automatic");
        Transmission.Add("Manual");


        return Transmission;
    }

     Car car = _repository.GetCarDetails(id);

     ViewBag.Transmission = new SelectList(GetTransmissions(), car.Transmission);
```

In my view I have:

```
    @Html.DropDownList("Transmission", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Transmission, "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: What is `car.Transmission` referring to? Is it a class of some sort or a string?

Comment: Car is a class which has an attribute called Transmission of type string

Comment: show rendered html of drop down

Comment: Use a view model instead of using viewbag if you can, much better practice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Managed to fix by changing

```
 ViewBag.Transmission = new SelectList(GetTransmissions(), car.Transmission);
```

To

```
 ViewBag.Transmissions = new SelectList(GetTransmissions(), car.Transmission);
```

The Car model already contains an attribute called Transmission so need need for another ViewBag to hold this attribute.

In the my razor code use the following instead

```
  @Html.DropDownList("Transmission", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Transmissions, "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to differentiate the property that holds the list and the property that holds the selected value.

I recommend using a viewmodel for the view like this:

```
public class CarViewModel
{

    public SelectList Transmissions
    {
        get
        {
            return new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>{
                new SelectListItem {  Value = "Manual"},
                new SelectListItem {  Value = "Automatic"}
            });                
        }
    }

    public string Transmission { get; set; }

}
```

and use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee703567(v=vs.118).aspx) DropDownListFor version

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Transmission,
    @Model.Transmissions, "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are restricted to using `ViewBag` rather than a View Model and an `@Html.DropDownList` Html Helper then I would do the following:

```
        ViewBag.Transmissions = new SelectList(GetTransmissions()
        .Select(t => new {value = t, text = t}), 
            "value", "text");
        ViewBag.Transmission = car.Transmission;
```

The above creates the `SelectList`, then projects so that your dropdown renders text and values. This is saved in the `ViewBag.Transmissions`, which is the available options.

Then set your selected transmission with `ViewBag.Transmission`.

Your razor code would also need to be changed to use `ViewBag.Transmissions` too:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Transmission", 
      (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Transmissions, 
         "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pbnzVq)