# Dropdown list with ajax generated options not saving for CityId property

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have been trying for three days, but I could not figure out the mistakes because the code is correct, but its implementation is not what I want.
i am using three tables State,City and Donator,i want donator to select it's state and city  when select state it display the specified city but when save its informatio the cityId don't save as in the image as at the end.

i use ap.net mvc 5 code first.

any one can help and tell me how to solve this problem
the following my Models,Controller,and View:

```
public enum Gender
    { Male, Femal }
    public class Donator
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Gender gender { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string BloodType { get; set; }
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("StateId")]
        public State state { get; set; }

    }

//State Table
 public class State
    {
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<City> cities { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Donator> donS { get; set; }
    }

//City table
     public class City
    {
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("StateId")]
        public State state { get; set; }
    }
//Donators Controller
public class DonatorsController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET: Donators
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Donators.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Donators/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Donator donator = db.Donators.Find(id);
        if (donator == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(donator);
    }

    // GET: Donators/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.StateId = new SelectList(db.state, "StateId", "StateName");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Donators/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,gender,Age,BloodType,CountryId,StateId")] Donator donator)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Donators.Add(donator);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.StateId = new SelectList(db.state, "StateId", "StateName", donator.StateId);

        return View(donator);
    }

    // GET: Donators/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Donator donator = db.Donators.Find(id);
        if (donator == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        ViewBag.StateId = new SelectList(db.state, "StateId", "StateName", donator.StateId);
        return View(donator);
    }

    // POST: Donators/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,gender,Age,BloodType,StateId,CityId")] Donator donator)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(donator).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.CountryId = new SelectList(db.country, "CountryId", "CountryName");
        return View(donator);
    }

    // GET: Donators/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Donator donator = db.Donators.Find(id);
        if (donator == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(donator);
    }

    // POST: Donators/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Donator donator = db.Donators.Find(id);
        db.Donators.Remove(donator);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    public JsonResult StateList(int Id)
    {
        var state = from s in db.state
                    where s.CountryId == Id
                    select s;
        return Json(new SelectList(state.ToArray(), "StateId", "StateName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult Citylist(int id)
    {
        var city = from c in db.city
                   where c.StateId == id
                   select c;
        return Json(new SelectList(city.ToArray(), "CityId", "CityName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    public IList<State> Getstate(int CountryId)
    {
        return db.state.Where(m => m.CountryId == CountryId).ToList();
    }
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult LoadClassesByCountryId(string CountryName)
    {
        var stateList = this.Getstate(Convert.ToInt32(CountryName));
        var stateData = stateList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = m.StateName,
            Value = m.CountryId.ToString(),
        });
        return Json(stateData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

}

//Create View

```
@model WebApplication6.Models.Donator

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Create</title>
</head>
<body>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script type="text/jscript">
    $(function () {
        $('#State').change(function () {
            $.getJSON('/Donators/Citylist/' + $('#State').val(), function (data) {
                var items = '<option>Select a City</option>';
                $.each(data, function (i, city) {
                    items += "<option value='" + city.Value + "'>" + city.Text + "</option>";
                });
                $('#city').html(items);
            });
        });
    });
    </script>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Donator</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BloodType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BloodType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BloodType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StateId, "StateId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("StateId", null, htmlAttributes: new {id="State", @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StateId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CityId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("City", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { id = "city", @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CityId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

donator create view:

[image: image of donator create view]

after save donator info(index view)
[image: image of after save donator info(index view]

Comment: Excuse me, why did no one answer my question?i'm a biginner

Comment: HI, welcome to SO. You've asked this question 2 hours ago, sometimes it takes more time for a question to reach the audience. While waiting i suggest you change the question title similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295193/asp-mvc-dropdown-list-selected-value-not-selected but stressing out the specificity.

Comment: Oky!i'm waitting until any One help me,thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your POST create controller action, you are not binding CityId. You're binding CountryId, is that a typo?

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,gender,Age,BloodType,CountryId,StateId,CityId")] Donator donator)
{
   // add cityId to the bind parameters above
   ...
}
```

You'll need to update `City` to `CityId` on your html helper.

```
// please update first string parameter to CityId
@Html.DropDownList("CityId", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { id = "city", @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: oh!i'm sorry i'm already binding it but,the problem stay exist

Comment: @borhanoz update first string parameter to CityId `@Html.DropDownList("CityId", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { id = "city", @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer helped me solve my problem. I don’t know what sins I committed. Sometimes a little problem is too late,Thanks again.

Comment: @borhanoz We all make mistakes, they're not sins haha! You're welcome, please mark the answer as the correct answer if it did help. Thanks!

Comment: there is another problem how to solve editting problem when i click editing it don't show dropdown list for cities to specified state how to edit the script? please!

Comment: @borhanoz will you open another question and include the controller action, view, and scripts there. I'll have a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211667/discussion-between-borhanoz-and-jerdine-sabio).

Comment: @borhanoz hey man, sorry I'm not allowed to open other chat apps while at work. Link me the question once you've made one