# Dropdown list with ajax generated options display all cities for different states in the edit view until selected state changed it becomes normal

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

this occur only first time the edit view shown but after change the selected state it becomes normal, how to control dropdown list to display only cities for specific state in the edit view?is the problem in edit action or in ajax script?Maybe my question is simple but I want to learn, I am grateful to you? 
i'm using asp.net mvc 5 code first.the following is my controller action and view with scripts. [models are in previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212504/dropdown-list-with-ajax-generated-options-not-saving-for-cityid-property)

```
    //Donator Controller
        public class DonatorsController : Controller
        {
            private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

            // GET: Donators
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                var donators = db.Donators.Include(d => d.cit).Include(d => d.state);
                return View(donators.ToList());
            }

            // GET: Donators/Details/5
            public ActionResult Details(int? id)
            {
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
                Donator donator = db.Donators.Find(id);
                if (donator == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                return View(donator);
            }


            // GET: Donators/Edit/5
            public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
            {
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
                Donator donator = db.Donators.Find(id);
                if (donator == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                ViewBag.StateId = new SelectList(db.state, "StateId", "StateName", donator.StateId);
                ViewBag.CityId = new SelectList(db.city, "CityId", "CityName", donator.CityId);
                return View(donator);
            }

            // POST: Donators/Edit/5
            // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
            // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
            [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,gender,Age,BloodType,StateId,CityId")] Donator donator)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                    db.Entry(donator).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                ViewBag.StateId = new SelectList(db.state, "StateId", "StateName", donator.StateId);
                ViewBag.CityId = new SelectList(db.city, "CityId", "CityName", donator.CityId);

                return View(donator);
            }

            public JsonResult Citylist(int id)
            {
                var city = from c in db.city
                           where c.StateId == id
                           select c;
                return Json(new SelectList(city.ToArray(), "CityId", "CityName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
}

    //Edit View




    l CCR.Models.Donator

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    }

    <h2>Edit</h2>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script type="text/jscript">
        $(function () {
           

            $('#State').change(function () {
                $.getJSON('/Donators/Citylist/' + $('#State').val(), function (data) {
                    var items = '<option>Select a City</option>';
                    $.each(data, function (i, city) {
                        items += "<option value='" + city.Value + "'>" + city.Text + "</option>";
                    });
                    $('#city').html(items);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Donator</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BloodType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BloodType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BloodType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StateId, "StateId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("StateId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "State" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StateId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CityId, "CityId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("CityId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "city" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CityId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
```

Comment: @Jerdine Sabio help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind State Dropdown list with model value like below

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=> x.StateId, ViewBag.StateId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "State" })
```

rename `ViewBag.StateId` to `Viewbag.States` because its select list for States
Same thing do with City dropdown.

Another thing I want to tell you, write javascript code at the bottom of page & write `$('#State').change` event in `document.ready` instead of autorun javascript function

Comment: Hi,I did not understand what you mean by writing this amendment,is write it in my controller?

Comment: 1) You are not binding model/database value to dropdown list so you have to use dropdownlistFor

Comment: Anothing thing is the JS function you wrote is "autorun function" try to google it, if you are not aware. Write that part in document.ready method

Comment: This code executes naturally, but the problem is when I click on the Edit link then well show information for specefic donator  when I click on the dropdown list of cities it exposes all cities in the table and when I click on the dropdown  list of states it works normally(it shows cities for specefic state), I think that the JS code needs some edit